# VideoView and MediaController within a DayDream?

Tags: android, android-videoview, daydream

I got the following exception:

```
02-10 15:30:03.676  12841-12841/hu.stuff.dreamE/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: hu.stuff.dream, PID: 12841
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:536)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
            at android.widget.VideoView$5.onError(VideoView.java:516)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2248)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:731)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

For the following code:

```
public class MyDreamService extends DreamService {
    VideoView vidView;

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        setInteractive(false);
        setFullscreen(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDreamingStarted() {
        super.onDreamingStarted();
        vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
        vidView.setVideoPath("Voice_Activated_Corgi.mp4");
        vidView.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDreamingStopped() {
        super.onDreamingStopped();
        vidView.stopPlayback();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }
}
```

Quite obviously, the problem is that this is not an `Activity` context, this is a `Window` within a `DreamService`. I don't really want to start an Activity from the service (that'd ruin the point of the daydream, wouldn't it?) but I also don't really want to reimplement the VideoView.

Although I'm most likely going to have to go another route instead of VideoView and hope they don't use Dialogs underneath (MediaPlayer and SurfaceView).

Any ideas on how to fix the problem of using `VideoView` in a `DreamService`'s `Window` without getting `BadTokenException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MediaPlayer and SurfaceView approach worked.

```
public class MyDreamService extends DreamService implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceHolder vidHolder;
    private SurfaceView vidSurface;

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        setInteractive(false);
        setFullscreen(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        vidSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfView);
        vidHolder = vidSurface.getHolder();
        vidHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDreamingStarted() {
        super.onDreamingStarted();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDreamingStopped() {
        super.onDreamingStopped();
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice_activated_corgi);
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mediaPlayer.setDisplay(vidHolder);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

and

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Based on the guide at

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/streaming-video-in-android-apps--cms-19888

Note: I have a feeling I need to handle the `onDreamStarted()` and the `onPrepared()` in a bit smarter fashion. But it works as of now. But if I needed the `MediaController`, then that'd get a bit more difficult.